# how could i solve my problem in my python code?

Tags: python

In first line it showing Syntax error at ' '0': ', this is my code:

```
if testset_err + validset_err + trainset_err == '0':    
    print ('Checking test PASSED.')
else:
    print ('Checking test FAILED.')

if raw_input('Do you want to save results to data.mat (Y/n)? ') == 'Y':
    print ('... saving datasets')
```

Comment: First things first, indent properly your code both in this site and when coding. It's of the utmost importance in Python.

Comment: Check the line before this.

Answer (score 0):

The '0' in the first IF statement is an integer,but it is a literal. Unless the variables are equal to the integer 0 as a literal then the code will not work. If you want to structure your variables like that then it is much better to do the following:

```
if testset_err + validset_err + trainset_err==0:
    print('Checking test PASSED.')
```